# How to select column from a table using sql?

Tags: sql, multiple-columns

I have a table like this.

| Name | c1 | c2 | c3 | c4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| one | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| one | 3 | 1 | 7 | 6 |
| one | 5 | 9 | 2 | 5 |
| one | 2 | 5 | 1 | 8 |
| two | 1 | 4 | 2 | 6 |
| two | etc..... |  |  |  |

I want to select a column randomly with the condition name equal to one.

The result should be like this:

| c1 (This column will selected randomly) |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 3 |
| 5 |
| 2 |

Comment: Is this for SQL Sever, Oracle, MySQL or ...?

Answer (score 3):

How about a simple,

```
 select <col_name> from <table_name> where name = 'one';
```

Comment: Thanks its working but not selecting randomly... i want to select column c1 or c2 or c3 or c4 randomly.. any idea?

Answer (score 1):

```
select <col_name> from <table_name> where name = 'one' order by newid();
```

The order by newid() function call will help randomise the row returned.

Answer (score 1):

```
      SELECT <col_name> FROM <table_name> WHERE name = 'one' ORDER BY RAND() Limit 1
```

Comment: Is a simple `SELECT` but consider adding some comments to clarify your answer to the OP and future visitors

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't know your DBMS, here is a DBMS agnostic query that will select randomly a column from your table:

```
SELECT
   CASE round(3*rand()+1)
      WHEN 1 THEN c1
      WHEN 2 THEN c2
      WHEN 3 THEN c3
      WHEN 4 THEN c4 
   END;
FROM
   <table_name>
WHERE 
   name = 'one'
```

**where**

`round()` is function that rounds its argument.

```
round(1.23) = 1
round(-1.58) = -2
```

**and**

`rand()` is a function that generates a random value `v` in the range `0 <= v < 1.0`.

```
rand() => 0.123687466
rand() => 0.996574545
```